# LightSwitch Application and Doing //Something when a row value has been changed

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a LightSwitch application (C#) and it's all working fine, but am in need of a feature and not sure how to go about it.

Let's say that there is a Status column in my Orders screen. And when I change a status to, say, "Confirmed" in the Status column, I would like to send an e-mail to the email address corresponding to that particular person about their order.

Is this even possible in LightSwitch applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly this sounds like exactly what LightSwitch is intended for.

What I would do is that I would add a changed handler for Status field on the Orders table (so that's it's available in all screens).

Something like this:

```
public partial class Order
{
    partial void Status_Changed()
    {
      if (status == Status.Confirmed)
      {
         // Write code to send email
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you: What would the code to send email be? I know how to do it with webbased apps and with WinForms apps, but System.Net.Mail is not available in LightSwitch apps, it doesn't exist. The only usings available are System.Net.Browser, System.Net.NetworkInformation and System.Net.Sockets - :S

Comment: It seems like there's a little bug in Visual Studio Ultimate. If I write code, and then type the using declaration, it doesn't seem to acknowledge that I've typed the using declaration.

Comment: FYI, this guy seems to be doing something similar to what you need: http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Forum/tabid/63/aft/75/Default.aspx